# app crash when using Geolocation in React-Native

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I am using `react-native-geolocation-service`, I have such function to get coords. And then by Geocoder api get the city by coords. I check the permission status by `react-native-permissions`:

```
export const getCity = async (dispatch: Dispatch<any>) => {
  const granted = await check(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

  if (granted === RESULTS.DENIED) {
    await PermissionsAndroid.request(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, {
      buttonNegative: undefined,
      buttonNeutral: undefined,
      buttonPositive: '',
      title: 'Access',
      message: 'give access',
    });
  }

  if (granted === RESULTS.GRANTED || granted === RESULTS.LIMITED) {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const coords: Coords = {
          Longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          Latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        };
        dispatch(thunks.geocoder.getGeocoderInfo(coords));
        Alert.alert('coords', `${coords.Latitude}, ${coords.Longitude}`);
      },
      error => Alert.alert('Error', `Error ${error.message}`),
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: false,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 3600000,
      },
    );
  }
};
```

So, when my applications starts, I grant the permission to it, and then it just closes. Also I added access into `AndroidManifest.xml`: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`. And then I call this function inside my component using `UseEffect()`

Comment: Plug your phone into the computer, open Android Studio and run your app again. In the LogCat window you should see the error that's causing your app to crash. You can update your question with that error and then it will be easier for people to help you

Comment: @CarlosJ Tanks for your comment. I will try

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem. I rewrite my code form question as follows:

```
type Coords = {
  coords: {
    accuracy?: number | null;
    altitude?: number | null;
    altitudeAccuracy?: number | null;
    heading?: number | null;
    latitude?: number | null;
    longitude?: number | null;
    speed?: number | null;
  };
  mocked?: boolean;
  provider?: string;
  timestamp?: number | null;
};

export const getCity = async (dispatch: Dispatch<any>) => {
  const granted = await check(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
  let geoOptions = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeOut: 20000,
    maximumAge: 60 * 60 * 24,
  };
  const geoSuccess = (position: Coords) => {
    const coords = {
      Latitude: position.coords.latitude,
      Longitude: position.coords.longitude,
    };

    dispatch(thunks.geocoder.getGeocoderInfo(coords));
  };

  const geoFailure = (err: any) => {
    console.log({error: err.message});
  };

  if (granted === RESULTS.DENIED) {
    const data = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      {
        buttonNegative: undefined,
        buttonNeutral: undefined,
        buttonPositive: '',
        title: 'Access',
        message: 'give access',
      },
    );
  }

  if (granted === RESULTS.GRANTED || granted === RESULTS.LIMITED) {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess, geoFailure, geoOptions);
  }
};
```

So it solved my problem. App now doesn't crush.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by upgrading your react native to 0.70.1, i just solved that problem and now the gelocaiton service is working fine in both debug and release apk.
and dont forget to add use permission in androidmanifest.xml